# What Javascript constructs does JsLex incorrectly lex?

Tags: javascript, python, tokenize, lexical-analysis

[JsLex](https://bitbucket.org/ned/jslex) is a Javascript lexer I've written in Python.  It does a good job for a day's work (or so), but I'm sure there are cases it gets wrong.  In particular, it doesn't understand anything about semicolon insertion, and there are probably ways that's important for lexing.  I just don't know what they are.

What Javascript code does [JsLex](https://bitbucket.org/ned/jslex) lex incorrectly?  I'm especially interested in valid Javascript source where JsLex incorrectly identifies regex literals.

Just to be clear, by "lexing" I mean identifying tokens in a source file.  JsLex makes no attempt to parse Javascript, much less execute it.  I've written JsLex to do full lexing, though to be honest I would be happy if it merely was able to successfully find all the regex literals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interestingly enough I tried your lexer on the code of my lexer/evaluator written in JS ;) You're right, it is not always doing well with regular expressions. Here some examples:

```
rexl.re = {
  NAME: /^(?!\d)(?:\w)+|^"(?:[^"]|"")+"/,
  UNQUOTED_LITERAL: /^@(?:(?!\d)(?:\w|\:)+|^"(?:[^"]|"")+")\[[^\]]+\]/,
  QUOTED_LITERAL: /^'(?:[^']|'')*'/,
  NUMERIC_LITERAL: /^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?)?/,
  SYMBOL: /^(?:==|=|<>|<=|<|>=|>|!~~|!~|~~|~|!==|!=|!~=|!~|!|&|\||\.|\:|,|\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\}|\?|\:|;|@|\^|\/\+|\/|\*|\+|-)/
};
```

This one is mostly fine - only `UNQUITED_LITERAL` is not recognized, otherwise all is fine. But now let's make a minor addition to it:

```
rexl.re = {
  NAME: /^(?!\d)(?:\w)+|^"(?:[^"]|"")+"/,
  UNQUOTED_LITERAL: /^@(?:(?!\d)(?:\w|\:)+|^"(?:[^"]|"")+")\[[^\]]+\]/,
  QUOTED_LITERAL: /^'(?:[^']|'')*'/,
  NUMERIC_LITERAL: /^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?)?/,
  SYMBOL: /^(?:==|=|<>|<=|<|>=|>|!~~|!~|~~|~|!==|!=|!~=|!~|!|&|\||\.|\:|,|\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\}|\?|\:|;|@|\^|\/\+|\/|\*|\+|-)/
};
str = '"';
```

Now all after the `NAME's` regexp messes up. It makes 1 big string. I think the latter problem is that String token is too greedy. The former one might be too smart regexp for the `regex` token.

**Edit**: I think I've fixed the regexp for the `regex` token. In your code replace lines 146-153 (the whole 'following characters' part) with the following expression:

```
([^/]|(?<!\\)(?<=\\)/)*
```

The idea is to allow everything except `/`, also allow `\/`, but not allow `\\/`.

**Edit**: Another interesting case, passes after the fix, but might be interesting to add as the built-in test case:

```
    case 'UNQUOTED_LITERAL': 
    case 'QUOTED_LITERAL': {
        this._js =  "e.str(\"" + this.value.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\").replace(/"/g, "\\\"") + "\")";
        break;
    }
```

**Edit**: Yet another case. It appears to be too greedy about keywords as well. See the case:

```
var clazz = function() {
    if (clazz.__) return delete(clazz.__);
    this.constructor = clazz;
    if(constructor)
        constructor.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

It lexes it as: `(keyword, const), (id, ructor)`. The same happens for an identifier `inherits`: `in` and `herits`.

Comment: @configurator, yes, it parses both of them fine.

Comment: thanks for these cases, they helped find the problem with my regex-matching regex.  I haven't taken your solution, but instead removed the stupid error in mind: backslashes at the end of comments joined lines together, commenting out the recognition of escapes in character classes in regexes.  Thanks, I've added these cases to the test suite.

Comment: good point about the keywords.  I've fixed that now as well.  Keep 'em coming!

Comment: @Ned the latest code works just great. I've tested is on several rather big and sophisticated JS files with nasty regular expressions - it worked just brilliantly. Tried to beat it with some artificial (but valid) regexps - worked well again. Sometimes it breaks on illegal regexps like this one `/\/i`, but I'm not sure if you want to handle such cases at all. Thanks for an interesting problem, btw!

Answer (score 1):

Example: The first occurrence of `/ 2 /i` below (the assignment to `a`) should tokenize as *Div*, *NumericLiteral*, *Div*, *Identifier*, because it is in a *InputElementDiv* context. The second occurrence (the assignment to `b`) should tokenize as *RegularExpressionLiteral*, because it is in a *InputElementRegExp* context.

```
i = 1;
var a = 1 / 2 /i;
console.info(a); // ⇒ 0.5
console.info(typeof a); // number

var b = 1 + / 2 /i;
console.info(b); // ⇒ 1/2/i
console.info(typeof b); // ⇒ string
```

Source:

> There are two goal symbols for the lexical grammar. The *InputElementDiv* symbol is used in those syntactic grammar contexts where a division (`/`) or division-assignment (`/=`) operator is permitted. The *InputElementRegExp* symbol is used in other syntactic grammar contexts.
>
> Note that contexts exist in the syntactic grammar where both a division and a *RegularExpressionLiteral* are permitted by the syntactic grammar; however, since the lexical grammar uses the *InputElementDiv* goal symbol in such cases, the opening slash is not recognised as starting a regular expression literal in such a context. As a workaround, one may enclose the regular expression literal in parentheses.
> — *Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999*, p. 11

Comment: Thanks for the extra example.  I'm pleased to report that JsLex properly handles both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The simplicity of your solution for handling this hairy problem is very cool, but I noticed that it doesn't quite handle a change in `something.property` syntax for ES5, which allows reserved words following a `.`. I.e., `a.if = 'foo'; (function () {a.if /= 3;});`, is a valid statement in [some recent implementations.](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

Unless I'm mistaken there is only one use of `.` anyway for properties, so the fix could be adding an additional state following the `.` which only accepts the *identifierName* token (which is what *identifier* uses, but it doesn't reject reserved words) would probably do the trick. (Obviously the *div* state follows that as per usual.)

Comment: Interesting point.  I could argue that the lexer doesn't care about this point, it will be up to the grammar to allow a keyword as a property, I'm not sure.  For my purposes (finding strings and regexes), the different doesn't matter, but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about the problems of writing a lexer for JavaScript myself, and I just came across your implementation in my search for good techniques.  I found a case where yours doesn't work that I thought I'd share if you're still interested:

```
var g = 3, x = { valueOf: function() { return 6;} } /2/g;
```

The slashes should both be parsed as division operators, resulting in x being assigned the numeric value 1.  Your lexer thinks that it is a regexp.  There is no way to handle all variants of this case correctly without maintaining a stack of grouping contexts to distinguish among the end of a **block** (expect regexp), the end of a **function statement** (expect regexp), the end of a **function expression** (expect division), and the end of an **object literal** (expect division).

Answer (score 0):

Does it work properly for this code (this shouldn't have a semicolon; it produces an error when lexed properly)?

```
function square(num) {
    var result;
    var f = function (x) {
        return x * x;
    }
    (result = f(num));
    return result;
}
```

If it does, does it work properly for this code, that relies on semicolon insertion?

```
function square(num) {
    var f = function (x) {
        return x * x;
    }
    return f(num);
}
```

Comment: It does work fine for this code, because all it's doing is identifying tokens.  I'm mostly concerned with finding regex literals (I updated the question to make this clear).

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the first example is supposed to be an example of correct syntax or not.

Comment: @Zach: Correct syntax; incorrect code though. The function fails with a type error because it says `var f = function (x) { return x * x } (result = f(num));` thus applying f before it is set.

Comment: @Ned: I see. Regex literals are a finicky thing, hard to parse. I'd have to think about it for a while...

Comment: Actually, regex literals should be pretty easy. When you encounter a `/` which is not part of a comment or a division, everything until the next `/` which is not preceded by `\` is part of the regex literal.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: you might want to investigate more before declaring something "pretty easy".  For example, how do you determine that the / isn't part of a division?  And slashes can also appear inside a regex like `/[/]/`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: It's actually extremely complicated. They can look like division unless you pay close attention to details. Division: `a/(b+c/d+e)/g`, Regex: `/(b+c/d+e)/g`.